# How can I use Wordpress' REST Api to access data on my local host?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, rest, jquery

I've been working on a wordpress blog on my local host and I need to do a proof of concept with the wordpress' REST Api - how can I request data from something on my local host? I couldn't find much documentation on how to use the REST Api, can someone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this using Wordpress' REST API as it is only for blogs on the Wordpress domain. However, there are several plugins for Wordpress blogs created by other users which you can install locally and use to access your data through REST API calls.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, using Jetpack, you now have access to the REST API as long as your self hosted WordPress is activated with Jetpack ;) Working on using this right now. http://developer.wordpress.com/2012/10/26/using-the-rest-api-with-wordpress-org-self-hosted-sites-via-jetpack/